# When using jQuery plugin collagePlus img-tag is appended with entire body content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, joomla2.5, mootools

I´m having a serious problem on my Joomla site.
Joomla 2.5 latest version.

On all pages there are no jQuery conflicts or errors in developers panel (Chrome)
But when I use the plugin collagePlus something very weird happens..

Here is the base HTML layout for collagePlus image gallery:

```
<section class="Collage effect-parent">    

<div class="Image_Wrapper" data-caption="test....">
<a title="test" class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/demo/placeholder-large.jpg">
<img class="collageimgs" src="/images/demo/placeholder-large.jpg" alt="test">
</a>
</div>
<div class="Image_Wrapper" data-caption="test....">
<a title="test" class="fancybox" rel="group" href="/images/demo/placeholder-large.jpg">
<img class="collageimgs" src="/images/demo/placeholder-large.jpg" alt="test">
</a>
</div>

</section>
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
       jQuery('.Collage').collagePlus();
});
```

Whenever the page loads the entire body content of the page is appended into each img container inside the Wrapper divs.
This is very strange indeed.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: Why did you tag MooTools?

Comment: This is due to the fact that Joomla 2.5 has built in MooTools, and I cannot be certain that this problem is not caused by some form of conflict between jQuery and MooTools.

Comment: The collagePlus [is not using the __$__](https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/master/jquery.collagePlus.js#L401), so I don't see how that plugin could interfere with MooTools. Anyway, do you see any error in the console log?

Comment: Hi again, I do see some errors regarding mootools in Chrome developers panel on the page where the collagePlus plugin is loaded but not on any other pages. "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" but I cannot see what is the cause of this.. I can send you a PM if you want to take a quick look at it

Comment: The best is if you post here, a screenchot, a gist, jsfiddle or a link so more people can see. There are some MooTools fanatics around that can help.

Comment: this will be a problem with the way the plugin is written. post the link to the source code on github or in a gist.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/uZv3n/1558/ - with mootools on the page, there is no impact whatsoever and works as expected. check your markup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have now made a demo on my own page where there is also a problem.
See this page:
http://www.genius-webdesign.com/gallery-demo

Comment: The demo is located on a Joomla site with Joomla! 3.3.1

Comment: I found that disabling jquery.lazyload.min.js in the template solved the white screen. But there is still a problem. The images do not load and when I go to dev panel in Chrome the page goes white screen..

Comment: For the time being I´m trying other plugins on my test site. Regarding the site in question with the weird appending to the img tag I will post a link once the site goes live, which is very soon.

Comment: Hello Dimitar, are you still watching this post?

Comment: If so, I would like to give you access to the front end so you can see the problem first hand.